# Scrapy pagination with __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION after page 10

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to crawl ASP.NET site, but I can't paginate through page 10.

The scenario:

AJAX pagination like this:
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/R86QF.png)

Thank you to [Scrapy works fine until page 12 of asp site, then 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836227/scrapy-works-fine-until-page-12-of-asp-site-then-500-error), the problem is very similar to mine

When the spider perform a FormRequest.from_response to AJAX, it doesn't get the `__EVENTVALIDATION` and `__VIEWSTATE` from the next response (just the content generated by `__POSTBACK` - I think - not the full HTML), so it can't make another call to paginate through page 10.

My approach to get the pages 1-10 is something like this:

```py
def pages(self, response):
   for page in pages:
      head = {'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true'}
      data = {'__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabPedidos$tabAComprar$gvAComprar',
              '__EVENTARGUMENT': 'Page${}'.format(page),
              'ctl00$ScriptManager1': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$upPanel|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabPedidos$tabAComprar$gvAComprar',
              '__ASYNCPOST': 'true',
              '__EVENTVALIDATION': response.css('input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').extract_first(),
              '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first(),
              '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').extract_first(),
              '__AjaxControlToolkitCalendarCssLoaded': '',
              'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabPedidos_ClientState': '{"ActiveTabIndex":0,"TabState":[true,true]}',
              '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': ''}
      yield FormRequest.from_response(response, url=url, callback=self.parse_ajax, formdata=data, headers=head, dont_click=True)

def parse_ajax(self, response):
   # some xpath parse in there
   yield item
```

When the spider try to crawl pages > 11, he put me back in page 1. How can I reach this pages? There's a better way to make this AJAX requests (or even paginate)?

Also, I tried to use Selenium and Scrapy-Splash, but the performance are way too low.